# is it ok to read aspx/cshtml files that are also used by the asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want the user to be able to see the source code of the page that he is on, so I'm planing to just read the file from the file system (`Server.MapPath("~/Views/home/index.aspx"`)) and output it into html.

I'm just wondering if there is any problem with this approach, like if the asp.net process is locking the aspx/cshtml files or something like that

Comment: Well, they are compiled. But with that name, I can't take you seriously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is perfectly alright. 
Asp.net does not lock onto the aspx files. 
It reads these files on first request, and stores in a format it IL format compiled code, and from then on only watches the original aspx for changes.
If the file changes it is recompiled.

Ref: [dynamic compilation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366723.aspx)

I could not find any docs to support this, but you should have no trouble if you read the aspx file.